# How to create table with data stored in columns instead of rows?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns: store id, product type, product quantity like this:

```
store1 shirt 3
store1 hat   2
store2 shirt 1
store3 hat   4
```

I want to convert this table to the following format (with shirt quantity in column 2 and hat quantity in column 3):

```
store1 3 2
store2 1 -
store3 - 4
```

How do I write my `select` statement to do this? Thanks.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: You want to change your table, or you want to create a redundant copy of your table?

Comment: I want to create a new table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try multiple aggregations on the rows:

```
SELECT store, Sum(CASE WHEN product='shirt' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS shirts,
    Sum(CASE WHEN product='hat' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS hats
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY store
```

If that is not what you mean, you will have to provide more information.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thanks so much.